# Dojo Campus - links

Tags: dojo

(This is partly a question, partly a request to the Dojo Campus folks; they suggest using SO for communication of support questions, and partly a "here's a useful link" to guide people like me who are lost in dojo.)

Can anyone find a way, in two clicks or fewer, to get from the [home page](http://dojocampus.org/) of the Dojo Campus to any of the excellent reference material? All pages on the site have a link to "home", which takes us to a page of interesting stuff and a search box. Neither of which seem to take us to the **really good** stuff linked from [the welcome page](http://docs.dojocampus.org/manual/index). Innocent readers might wonder why the "home" page is not the "welcome" page.

Comment: There is a redesign pending on the sites (dojotoolkit.org and dojocampus.org) that hopefully will address these problems.

Comment: Much needed, any ideas when the redesign will go live?

Comment: My fault, we're working on it. The site _should_ be launched around the time 1.4 is released.